# How to see if a modifier key is being held down without catching the keydown event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, google-chrome-extension

I know how to catch keyup and keydown events.

I want my program to see which modifier keys (eg: meta key, control key, alt key, etc.) are currently being held down even if the program didn't observe the keydown events of those keys.

I know that click events and other events can tell me which modifier keys were pressed down when they were fired off, but my program can't wait around for one to occur.

I need my program to check for the modifier keys regularly (say, every 100ms). How would I go about doing this? My program uses jQuery if that helps.

Comment: This can't be done unless you use an event listener.

Comment: Do you mean I need an actual event (and not a simulated one) to be fired off in order to know which modifier keys were pressed down?

Comment: If the answer below is not acceptable, I would say that you very likely have an X Y problem. Instead of telling us what you are trying to *do*, explain the problem you are actually trying to solve. That is, Why are you wanting to do this? There may be a better way.

Answer (score 4):

You can store those values in a variable, and check them whenever you want. An event listener will be necessary of course to update that variable:

```js
// assume no hot key is pressed

var object = {
  ctrlKey: false,
  altKey: false,
  shiftKey: false
};

// update whenever a keydown or keyup event is fired

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  for(var key in object) {
    if(object.hasOwnProperty(key))
      object[key] = e[key]; // update the object from the event e
  }
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  for(var key in object) {
    if(object.hasOwnProperty(key))
      object[key] = e[key];
  }
});

// testing example:

function check() {
  console.log("Checking:");
  console.log("Alt key:", object.altKey);
  console.log("Ctrl key:", object.ctrlKey);
  console.log("Shift key:", object.shiftKey);
}

setInterval(check, 1000); // calling check every second without waiting for an event to occur
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the issue is that my program can't make the assumption from your first line. It doesn't know whether a modifier key was initially being held down or not.

Comment: @Sophtware the program makes no such assumption, it simply starts off with the keys not pressed. Unless your users are loading pages while holding a modifier key down, this should work

Comment: @Sophtware Well, I don't think there is another way. Simulating an event doesn't seem to be telling whether a hot key is pressed.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Yeah, I figured that this was the case. It didn't work when I tried, but I was hoping I was doing something wrong or that there was another way.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but since this shows up on Google, here's a partial solution that's one step closer. From [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22086456/5711922):

```
document.body.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (e.which === 18) {
    alt_state.textContent = 'pressed';
  }
};

document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.which === 18) {
    alt_state.textContent = 'released';
  }
};

function detectAlt() {
  if (document.webkitHidden) return;
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', function onMove(e) {
    alt_state.textContent = e.altKey ? 'pressed' : 'released';
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMove, false);
  }, false);
}

document.addEventListener('webkitvisibilitychange', detectAlt, false);
window.addEventListener('load', detectAlt, false);
```

Essentially, set up a `mousemove` event listener, which contains the modifier key states when fired, and remove the listener after it's fired the first time. Again, still requires an "event" but depending on your application's expected usage, catching the first `mousemove` event might be sufficient for detecting modifier keys.